# Setting String with comma into a single variable in CSV file using TCL

Tags: csv, tcl

I'm having a Csv file like below:

```
Production,FALSE,Other Line,Release,UOF-919 BASE,3A001A11,9X999,PC,"Jap,Ind",006
```

And i'm reading and setting the values to a variable using tcl like below:

```
set fileIn [open "C:/myfile.csv" r]

        while {[gets $fileIn sLine] >= 0} {
            set lsLine [split $sLine ","]
            set sType "Hardware"
            set sName [lindex $lsLine 1]
            set Sdev [lindex $lsLine 2]
            set spara [lindex $lsLine 3]
            set sDescription [lindex $lsLine 4]
            set sManage [lindex $lsLine 5]
            set sconnect [lindex $lsLine 6]
            set sUOM [lindex $lsLine 7]
            set sCountry [lindex $lsLine 8]

            #my operations
            }
    flush $fileId
    close $fileId
    }
```

Here i'm not able to set **"Jap,Ind"** to **sCountry** because it already has one more comma inside the quotes. Can anybody help me to set that? I'm new in TCL.

Comment: The `"Jap,Ind"` element has index 8, not 9: indexes start with 0.

Comment: @Peter Lewerin :Sorry my mistake, corrected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`csv`](https://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/csv/csv.html) package (it is a package that has been included in the default libraries for a while now):

```
set fileIn [open "C:/myfile.csv" r]
package require csv
while {[gets $fileIn sLine] >= 0} {
    set lsLine [::csv::split $sLine]  # I'd use the -alternate 
                                      # switch if you can have empty elements
    set sType "Hardware"
    set sName [lindex $lsLine 0]
    set Sdev [lindex $lsLine 1]
    set spara [lindex $lsLine 2]
    set sDescription [lindex $lsLine 3]
    set sManage [lindex $lsLine 4]
    set sconnect [lindex $lsLine 5]
    set sUOM [lindex $lsLine 6]
    set sPin [lindex $lsLine 7]
    set sCountry [lindex $lsLine 8]

    #my operations
}

flush $fileId
close $fileId
```

Note that I also changed the indices. Tcl lists are 0-based, meaning that the first element of a list has the index 0. `[lindex $lsLine 0]` thus gives the first element from the list `$lsLine`.

And maybe if you want to make the code shorter, you could use [`lassign`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lassign.htm) (as of Tcl 8.5)

```
set fileIn [open "C:/myfile.csv" r]
package require csv
while {[gets $fileIn sLine] >= 0} {
    set lsLine [::csv::split $sLine]
    set sType "Hardware"
    lassign $lsLine sName Sdev spara sDescription sManage sconnect sUOM sPin sCountry

    #my operations
}

flush $fileId
close $fileId
```

---

Alternate solution if csv is not available which works for most cases (Tcl 8.6):

```
set lsLine [lmap {a b} [regexp -all -inline -- {("[^\"]+"|[^,]*)(?:$|,)} $sLine] {set b}]
```

Tcl 8.5:

```
set matches [regexp -all -inline -- {("[^\"]+"|[^,]*)(?:$|,)} $sLine]
set lsLine {}
foreach {a b} $matches {lappend lsLine $b}
```

The `\"` can be replaced with a simple `"` but I usually insert it if there's an issue with the code editor's syntax highlighting.

For more complex cases where escaped characters with a backslash can be involved (Tcl 8.6):

```
set lsLine [lmap {a b} [regexp -all -inline -- {("(?:\\.|[^\"])+"|(?:\\.|[^,])*)(?:$|,)} $sLine] {set b}]
```

Tcl 8.5:

```
set matches [regexp -all -inline -- {("(?:\\.|[^\"])+"|(?:\\.|[^,])*)(?:$|,)} $sLine]
set lsLine {}
foreach {a b} $matches {lappend lsLine $b}
```

Comment: Thank you so much jerry.:) I have one doubt here. Sometimes i will not have continuous column numbers. i may want like `2,5,6,7,9`. In that case how to use the second approach `lassign`?

Comment: And am getting `can't find package csv error`. what could be the possible reason?

Comment: @Crazy2crack `lassign` allows you to assign the variables from a list to individual named variables. E.g. in the above, I used `-` for a variable that I will not need. E.g. I have a list `$l` with ` a b c d` and I need only the 2nd and th, I can do `lassign $l - 2ndvar - 4thvar`

Comment: Yeah got it..Thank u..! and about the error? i'm having tcl version 8.5

Comment: @Crazy2crack Tcl probably cannot find the module. You can copy the module folder `C:\Tcl\lib\teapot\package\tcl\teapot\tcl8` to `C:\Tcl\lib`

Comment: There should be a file called `csv-0.8.tm` somewhere in the Tcl folder, this is what is required.

Comment: actually i dont have a separate Tcl software. I'm using tcl inside one of PLM software. :( is there any way i can check from command prompt?

Comment: @Crazy2crack You can add the folder path to `auto_path` (you'll have to insert it before `package require csv`): `lappend auto_path [file normalize C:\Tcl\lib\teapot\package\tcl\teapot\tcl8]` (or change that path to a more suitable one if the folder structure is different (If you can do a `dir /s` to see where it can be))

Comment: When i give `dir \s ` it is giving me `channel "console1" wasn't opened for writing`

Comment: Ok @jerry. Will try that. Thank you :)

Comment: there is some problem with the code i guess..`Double quotes` is missing somewhere in the code that u gave in comment. I'm not able to identify. can you please correct it? or if u can add it in the answer. it will be better for other users who don't have csv

Comment: I'm not getting the exact results. I mean the values are misplaced. Like for  `spara` i'm getting `Other Line` instead of release. And since three double quotes are there na , so code is also not formatted properly.

Comment: The misplacement problem is because i have some empty string @jerry. Like `Hardware,,test1,,item,` That space is not getting counted when i use above method

Comment: @Crazy2crack Ok, that makes things a bit more complex. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89640/discussion-between-crazy2crack-and-jerry).

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `split` to extract the variable (yes, your input is based on the comma, so we obviously go to that approach), the input's value should not have a 'comma' in it. To avoid that, we can replace it for a while and revert back wherever needed.

```
set fileIn [open "file.csv" r]

while {[gets $fileIn sLine] >= 0} {
    # Replacing the 'comma' with 'colon' and saving it into the save variable
    regsub {"(.*?),(.*?)"} $sLine {\1:\2} sLine
    set lsLine [split $sLine ","]

    # Your other indices can be processed and saved here


    # Getting the country values
    set sCountry [lindex $lsLine 8]; # Yes, the country value is available in '8th' index only, not on 9th. (Index starts with '0')

    # Replacing the 'colon' with 'comma' back again
    regsub : $sCountry , sCountry
    puts "Country Value : $sCountry"
}
close $fileIn
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Dinesh. it Worked :)

Comment: Note that this solution will fail if there are more than one quoted element in the line. If the `-all` option is used, it will still fail if there are more than one comma in a quoted element.

Comment: And it will not be ideal if the original text contains `:`. It really boils down to how 'wild' the text can be so you can use an appropriate approach, which not necessarily works for the 'wildest' cases.

Answer (score 1):

```
package require csv

set fileIn [open C:/myfile.csv r]

    while {[gets $fileIn sLine] >= 0} {
        set lsLine [csv::split $sLine]
        lassign $lsLine - sName Sdev spara sDescription sManage sConnect sUOM sCountry
    }

    close $fileId
}
```

Never try to parse CSV data with `split`. It will end in tears.

Note that this assumes that you want to assign to `sName` from index 1, i.e. the second element. The first element is assigned to the dummy variable `-`.

For sparse assignment, you can either use (assuming you want #8 rather than #9)

```
lassign $lsLine - - Sdev - - sManage sConnect sUOM sCountry
```

or

```
foreach idx {2 5 6 7 8} name {Sdev sManage sConnect sUOM sCountry} {
    set $name [lindex $lsLine $idx]
}
```

If you don't have `csv` installed, you can use `teacup install csv` from the command line to get it.

Documentation: [close](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/close.htm), [csv](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/csv/csv.html) package, [gets](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/gets.htm), [lassign](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lassign.htm), [open](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/open.htm), [package](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/package.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm), [while](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/while.htm)

Comment: yeah thank u @peter. I'll go through all those docs :) And Sometimes i will not have continuous column numbers. i may want like 2,5,6,7,9. In that case how to use this lassign?

Comment: how do i find whether it is installed or not @ Peter?

Comment: @Crazy2crack: if you get the message `can't find package csv` it's not installed.

Comment: i'm getting `invalid command name "teacup"` error while trying to install :(

Comment: @Crazy2crack: itc your Tcl installlation doesn't have the command. Not much to do.